# How to Use PageSpeed Insights API with Google API Python Client?

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client

I am currently working on the PageSpeed Insights api with Google API Python client. The API client states that 1000 requests can be done in one [Batch](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch). However I keep getting 500 errors after 26 requests. Is there a different way that the limit is calculated for PageSpeed Insights?

My current code is as following:

```
from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest
from apiclient.discovery import build

# URL_LIST = [ 998 lenghthed list of urls ]

def handle_metrics_results(request_id, response, exception):
        if exception is not None:
            # What say you?
            print 'Dude you fail! ' + str(exception)
        else:
            # Do something with result
            print 'Awesome! ' + str(response)

api_key = 'my_api_key'
insights_service = build('pagespeedonline', 'v2', developerKey=api_key)
insights_request_batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=handle_metrics_results)
for one_url in URL_LIST:
    insights_request_batch.add(
        insights_service.pagespeedapi().runpagespeed(url=one_url))
insights_request_batch.execute()
```

Could you please point me to the right direction? I really don't know what I am doing wrong here.